# Deleting Pointer shared with other class

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, shared-ptr

I'm having problems with memory deallocation in c++ using pointer shared between classes.

An example:

My vertices are defined as:

```
class Vertex{
    double x;
    double y;
}
```

A square is defined as:

```
class Square{
    Square(Vertex* a, Vertex* b, Vertex* c, Vertex* d);
    ~Square(); // destructor
    Vertex* a;
    Vertex* b;
    Vertex* c;
    Vertex* d;
}
```

My destructor is implemented so:

```
Square::~Square(){
    delete a;
    delete b;
    delete c; 
    delete d;
}
```

My squares are stored into `std::vector<Square*> squares`, so for clean all my memory I do:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < squares.size(); i++){
    delete(squares.at(i));
}
```

So what is the problem? If two squares share a Vertex, my program crash because it is trying to delete a pointer that no longer exists.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Don't manually allocate memory?

Comment: By using [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). That way, you wouldn't have to manage the memory yourself.

Comment: Shared pointer to Vertex is spelled `std::shared_ptr<Vertex>`.

Comment: [Using std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) which will call the destructor if no more objects are using it. Or using data on stack resulting in redundance if same vertices are "shared". For small objects like yours: `Vertex` this is not much memory overhead.

Comment: @AndreKampling There's many differences between using `std::vector` instead of `std::shared_ptr` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you are coding in C++ with a Java-like mindset. `Vertex` objects that contain just two `double`s (e.g. the X and Y components as in your case) are better stored on the stack, without pointer indirection. So, I would declare the `Square` class like this:

```
class Square{
...
  Vertex a;
  Vertex b;
  Vertex c;
  Vertex d;
};
```

If, instead of embedding `Vertex` objects you want a kind of reference mechanism, you could store the vertexes in a `std::vector<Vertex>` array, and store in the `Square` class integer *indexes* to vertex positions in the array.

If you *really* want shared ownership semantics with pointers, then consider using a **smart pointer** like `std::shared_ptr`. No explicit `delete`: `shared_ptr` will *automatically* release memory when the reference count reaches zero.

In this case, replace the raw `Vertex*` owning pointer data members with `shared_ptr<Vertex>` inside your `Square` class. Moreover, remove the destructor code from your `Square` class, as `shared_ptr` knows how to delete itself.

In your `Square` class constructor you can take the `shared_ptr<Vertex>` smart pointers by value, and `std::move` them inside the corresponding data members, e.g.:

```
Square::Square(
  std::shared_ptr<Vertex> pa,
  std::shared_ptr<Vertex> pb,
  std::shared_ptr<Vertex> pc
)
  : a{std::move(pa)}
  , b{std::move(pb)}
  , c{std::move(pc)}
{}
```

Replace also `vector<Square*>` with `vector<shared_ptr<Square>>` (but, again, are you sure that a simpler `vector<Square>` doesn't serve you well?), and use `std::make_shared` to create the smart pointers.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: In that case, those would be *observing* pointers, not owning pointers.

Comment: I know I provided a very simple example, but I really need share pointer beetween different classes for this reason I can't save vertex on the stack. 

If I use `shared_ptr`, I'll have to change a lot of code instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: @Steve If you _really_ want `shared_ptr`, then you can define `shared_ptr<Vertex>` data members inside your `Square` class (instead of raw `Vertex*`). Moreover, remove the destructor code from your `Square` class, as `shared_ptr` knows how to delete itself. Replace also `vector<Square*>` with `vector<shared_ptr<Square>>`, and use `std::make_shared` to create the smart pointers.

Comment: Thanks, now I try. If you edit your answer, I'll probably vote as answer that solved the problem

Comment: @Steve I've edited my answer incorporating the comment notes on `shared_ptr` usage.

Comment: My constructor was `Square::Square(Vertex* a, Vertex* b, Vertex*  c, Vertex* d)`. Now how it should be?

Comment: @Steve I edited my answer adding updated code for that constructor. Hope you find it useful.

Comment: compiler now say me that it need a costructor like: `Square::Square(Square*)` why?  What does it mean? 
What I have to do?

Comment: Maybe you need it in some other place of your code? Usually what is required is a _copy_ constructor like `Square(const Square&)`, and _move_ constructor like `Square(Square&&)`: those can be generated with the `=default` syntax (e.g. `Square(Square&&) = default;` `Square(const Square&) = default;`).

Answer (score 2):

You should never allocate memory manually in Modern C++, unless you have a very good reason to do so. If your `Square` class wants to model *shared ownership* of `Vertex` instances, then you should use `std::shared_ptr`:

```
class Square{
    // ...
    std::shared_ptr<Vertex> a, b, c, d;
}
```

I however advise you to reconsider using dynamic memory allocation for something as simple and lightweight as a `Vertex`.

Comment: I know I provided a very simple example, but I really need share pointer beetween different classes for this reason I can't save vertex on the stack.
My `std::vector<Square*>` is not on Square class, so I don't think is good to use share_ptr on that class.... Or it war only an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a legacy code and you cannot change the raw pointer to shared pointers or you cannot simply copy the vertexes (you want to reference the original objects), then don't delete the vertexes in the Square destructor, and possibly use a reference to the vertexes instead of a pointer.

You are already managing the allocation of Vertexes outside the Square object, so be sure to deallocate the vertexes only after all the squares have gone away.

The flow of the code would look like this:

- all the vertexes are allocated: a container keeps track of all the vertexes
- use the vertexes in multiple objects, possibly via a reference to them
- when all the objects using the vertexes have gone away then free all the vertexes in the container (if the container stores Vertex objects instead of pointers then just clear the container)